# Parts of PCA charts

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, data-analysis

There is a `Principal Components Analysis` chart: https://prnt.sc/j27oaf

I am not sure, on which vaulues are length of lines depends. How can I measure length of `PCA1`, `PCAX`? What is the meaning of lines above/below characters?

Answer (score 1):

More details could help, but I will try to guess the context.
I believe that $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ are the original data axes. While the plane that is spanned by $PC_1$ and $PC_2$ is in the directions of the most variation. While the third principle component ($PC_3$) is probably neglectable, hence your data (the points) are projected (the straight lines) into the space of the first two PCs. And I'm not sure what do you mean by the "length" of the PC. Any eigen-vector is normalized, so the length of the loadings is $1$, however if you meant to measure its contribution, then you can take the ratio of the eigenvalues. Namely, the contribution of $PC_1$ is $\lambda_1/\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i$. ( Note that $\operatorname{var}(PC_i) = \lambda_i$).